# How do i alphabetize this ArrayList without using the Collections.sort method?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, swap

This is a school assignment that I'm doing for fun. In this assignment, I am supposed to insert words into an ArrayList, then stop the ArrayList manually, then the program is supposed to alphabetize it. But the problem is, every tutorial tells me to use the Collections.sort method or something, but we haven't learned that in class, so we obviously aren't meant to use it. In addition, the challenge for this assignment is to sort everything inside 1 ArrayList instead of taking the words from an ArrayList, alphabetizing the words, then inserting the alphabetized words into a second ArrayList. Can someone help me sort this out? I haven't written anything in the alphabetize section because I don't know where to start. Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;

public class LexiHeaven {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a word into the Array (enter stop if you want to stop):");
        String w = sc.nextLine();

        while (!w.equals("stop")) {
            words.add(w);
            System.out.println("Please enter a word into the Array (enter stop if you want to stop):");
            w = sc.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println(words);
        System.out.println("Alphabetize the ArrayList:");

        String temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < words.size(); j++) {
                if (words.get(i).compareTo(words.get(j)) > 0) {
                    temp = words.get(i);
                    words.set(i, words.get(j));
                    words.set(j, temp);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(words);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest googling the phrase "bubble sort". It's one of the easier sorting techniques. Adding "java example" to the search might give you an example to follow.

Comment: You could use a sorting algorithm instead of using a method. These consist of looping through the ArrayList and comparing the Objects within based on parameters you set such as least to greatest or alphabetizing(basically the same thing just one is with numbers and the other a strings). Some easier ones include bubble sort, insertion sort, and selection sort.

Comment: i tried bubble sorting with temp, but it gives me an error saying that the left hand must be a variable. I dont know how to fix it.

Comment: This means that whatever is on the left of the assignment operator the `=` has to be a variable. Using `words.get(j)` is an accessor and returns a value. You are not actually able to mutate the value at index j when doing so, so using `=` will not work. You can use `words.set(j, temp)` to set the value at index j. `.set` is a mutator method and will allow you to change the value at index j. Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried it out, edits posted. but the thing is, words.set(i,j); isn't working. do you know why?

Comment: i cant use collections sort... i literally explained why in the question

Comment: In the code you posted, I don't see where you assign a value to local variable `temp`. Where is: `temp = ...` ?

Comment: You're welcome. Now, with that covered: look at your sorting code: `words.set(i,temp)` will set the list element at index `i` to the value in `temp`. But, that variable has no content. Then, you call `words.set(i, j)`, which immediately overwrites what you just did and sets the element at index `i` to the _number_ `j`, so you probably want to fix that. You're close: what you really want is to first do `temp = words.get(i)` so you don't lose the string you're about to overwrite, then you want to update `i` with the _word_ at index `j`, not just the number `j`. From there, you should be good.

Comment: ```String temp="";```
is this ok?

Comment: how do i set the word at index j? ive already tried this but words.get(j)=temp doesnt work

Comment: you don't, but you do need to write correct swapping code. The idea for swapping two elements `(a, b)` is to first do some kind of `temp = a` so that you can safely overwrite `a` with `b` (which gives you `(b,b)` as intermediate result), and then you can overwrite the original `b` with `temp` (which gives you the final `(b,a)`). If you look at your swapping code, that is not quite what you wrote yet.

Comment: ```temp=words.get(i);
words.set(i, temp);
words.set(i,words.get(j));
words.set(j, temp);``` was this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I can't explain myself well in a comment, so I will let my code do the talking for me.

Your loop that implements the bubble sort should be as follows:

```java
String temp;
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < words.size(); j++) {
        if (words.get(i).compareTo(words.get(j)) < 0) {
            temp = words.get(i);
            words.set(i, words.get(j));
            words.set(j, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this sorts the list in **descending** order because of the comparison you are doing, i.e.

```java
if (words.get(i).compareTo(words.get(j)) < 0) {
```

If you want ascending order, change `< 0` to `> 0`

I tried to explain, in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751443/how-do-i-alphabetize-this-arraylist-without-using-the-collections-sort-method#comment107505132_60751443), that you weren't assigning a value to local variable `temp` inside the loop.

Comment: thank you, i was getting confused over the i and j thing but it makes more sense now

Comment: i also really needed the >0 to sort everything in alphabetical order. thank you so much for that too

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the code you've written:

```
String temp;
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; j < words.size(); j++) {
    if (words.get(i).compareTo(words.get(j)) < 0) {
      words.set(i, temp);
      words.set(i,j);
      words.set(j, temp);
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't actually swap anything, though. Let's describe that inner loop in terms of code explanation:

```
if words[i] is alphabetically "lower" than words[j], do:
  - write the content of "temp" into words[i]
  - write the number "j" into words[i]
  - write the content of "temp" into words[j]
```

There are a few problems here:

1. you probably want to reverse that conditional, because you want (z,a) to become (a,z), not the other way around.
2. you never assign a value to `temp`, so this code will actually "corrupt" your list with `null` values,
3. you have two lines that write to the same index, so the first `words.set(i, temp)` basically "does nothing", even if it did do the right thing.

Let's fix that: swapping two elements in any array or list requires a third, temporary, placeholder. You put one of the two elements you want to swap into the temporary placeholder, then you overwrite that element with the value of the other element, and then you overwrite the over element with the temporary placeholder's value:

1. start with a list (a,b), a desire to swap elements 0 and 1, and some temp var
2. set temp = list[0], so we now have `list=(a,b), temp=a`.
3. overwrite list[0] with list[1], so we now have `list=(b,b), temp=a`
4. overwrite list[1] with your temp value, so we now have `list=(b,a), temp=a`

You're using your `temp` variable and ArrayList code, so that would be:

```
String temp;
for(...) {
  for(...) {
   if (...) {
     temp = words.get(i);
     words.set(i, words.get(j));
     words.set(j, temp);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this line of the code does not compile: `words.set(i,j);`

Comment: thank you for bearing with me. it all makes a lot more sense now after you've outlined each line. it works now :)